# git pull rebase freeze

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

I am able to pull succesfully previosuly, but today when I do git pull --rebase, it just shows this message

```
"Updating b4b1294473..22ceb04d88"
```

and it get stuck there forever.

It takes a lot of time to setup the git workspace, is there a workaround?

Comment: has to do with your internet connection ..

Comment: It's connected to internet

Comment: or maybe its not able to rebase and requires you to take manual steps. is there anything else in the logs.

Comment: do you know how to see the logs

Comment: what are the manual steps to get around this?

Comment: Try wiithout rebase first

Comment: tried git pull without rebase , and it stucks at "Updating b4b1294473..22ceb04d88" and 127 unrelated files from the other pull commits shown at my VSCode

Comment: Has your password expired. Try cloning in a separate directory

Comment: my ssh key is the same. Clone in a separate workspace will require a lot of disk space and  I will lost my stashed list

Comment: This is just to check everyting. So clone the repo elsewhere

Comment: define "forever"

Comment: In general, I prefer to do separate `git fetch` and second-command steps. If nothing else, this will tell you whether it's the fetch step that's taking "forever" (however long that is), or the rebase step. This then lets you drill down further into whatever is having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to inspect what git process is doing by tracing it with the following command:

```sh
strace -e trace=%network,%file git {{command line parameters}}
```

You should redirect the output to a file to inspect better the issue:

```sh
strace -e trace=%network,%file git {{command line parameters}} 2>&1 | tee /tmp/git.log
```

Comment: thanks. I tried another day and it's resolved with pull rebase command.